# Should I return success callback return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Is it conventional for parent function to return their child success callbacks or does it just depend on a case by case basis?

```
var cb = function(){
    return 1;
}

function ret_cb(succ_cb) {
    return(succ_cb ? succ_cb() : 1);
}

var succ = ret_cb(cb);
console.log(succ);

//or

function no_ret_cb(succ_cb) {
    if(succ_cb){
        succ_cb();
    }
    return 1;
}

succ = no_ret_cb(cb);
console.log(succ);
```

This would mainly be the reason I would use the callback

```
//functional way

succ = ret_cb(cb);

//vs

var some_value = "hello";
succ = ret_cb();
succ &= cb(some_value);
```

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the parent function and callback.

Comment: What kind of "success" is this?

Comment: it would be and arbitrary success based on the callback's purpose

Answer (score 2):

It's case by case.

It is rare for a function to take a callback and not be either asynchronous (in which case there is no return value from the callback to return until later) or operating in a loop (in which case there isn't **one** result of running the function to return).

Comment: …or in a conditional (which, arguably, might be a special case of a loop of length 0 or 1)

Comment: What if I wanted to pass some parameter to the success callback every to use functional programming instead of assigning the variable in the parent scope and then calling the success callback on parent scope as well.

Comment: @TheAschr — Then that would be a new and different question